# How to close a side bar in mobile view when user perform "scroll" or "touch" or "Click" Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web-applications

I am trying to developing a website, which contains a sidebar, navbar and body panel. It is a responsive website. In the mobile view when the user clicks on the hamburger icon a sidebar will open, So I wanted to close it after when the user performs any "Touch" event on the element other than sidebar i.e on the body panel.

Sidebar code:

```
<div id="sidebar-nav" class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-scroll">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li> Sidebar element </li>                
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="brand">
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn-toggle-fullwidth"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Body panel code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="main">
                <div class = "article_view"> 
                    <!-- this is the body panel -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note that I did for the click event. It is working properly.

```
$(".article_view").click(function(e) {
    if ($("body").hasClass("layout-fullwidth offcanvas-active")) {
         $("body").removeClass("layout-fullwidth offcanvas-active");
           $("body").toggleClass("undefined")
    }
})
```

For example:

Open `youtube.com` in mobile view and open sidebar and perform events on body such as touch, or swipe. Automatically sidebar will close. (I wanted to do like this)

Open `stackoverflow.com's` sidebar and perform the same events as swipe or touch. The sidebar will not close.

Please let me know how to handle touch events in the mobile view (swipe left, swipe down, swipe right or touch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code is a simple sidebar menu for your case.
When you open the sidebar menu an overlay drop the top of your elements and opened sidebar that is top of it.

onClose event fire when user click or touch on the overlay, So you don't need to onScroll event, Overlay not scrollable

```js
function overlay(isShow){
  var elm = document.getElementById('overlay')
  if (isShow) {
    elm.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    elm.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function openNav() {
  overlay(true);
 document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width="250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  overlay(false);
 document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width="0"
}
```

```css
 .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
 }

 .sidenav a{

  display: block;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  transition: 0.3s;
 }
 
 .sidenav a:hover{

  color: #F1F1F1;

 } 

 .sidenav .closebtn{
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 50px;
 }
  
  #overlay{
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
  }

 @media screen and (max-height: 450px){

  .sidenav{padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a{font-size: 18px;}

 }
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
 <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
</div>
<h2>Animated Sidenav</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open sidenav</p>
<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="openNav()">Menu</span>
<div id="overlay" onclick="closeNav()" ontouchstart="closeNav()" onscroll="closeNav()"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Mohammad Reza. The code what you gave handling "click events" properly. I tried this code but it is unable to handle touch events. You can check it in google chrome Developer options and see for mobile view. Open sidebar and perform any "touch events". Once again thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MuraliKrishnaBellamkonda Check again in the google chrome Developer options. `ontouchstart="closeNav()"` added.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please consider providing more info like what are you components. You can also include a demo snippet that shows your shell running. Apart from that I may have a solution. You can just change your event binding like so and it should work
(This assumes that your primary users do not have hybrid mobiles like certain blackberrys)

```
 $(".article_view").on("touchstart click", function(e) {
     if ($("body").hasClass("layout-fullwidth offcanvas-active")) {
        $("body").removeClass("layout-fullwidth offcanvas-active");
        $("body").toggleClass("undefined")
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is your solution**

```js
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click', closeNav);

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "230px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0;
  /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px;
  /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}


/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}


/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
<span onclick="openNav()">Siderbar Button click here</span>

<div id="main" style="height:100vh;">
  Body content is here
</div>
```